# Large Serialized PHP Array file

Tags: php, performance, optimization, serialization, multidimensional-array

I am working with a large PHP file that contains 1 very large serialized array. The use-case is fairly simple, we unserialize the big array at runtime, and utilise some of the array nodes as variables.

The file recently grew from ~6mb to >40mb, and so the load-time of the page based on it is now taking longer than 12 seconds.

I've SPLIT the file into 2 almost equal parts - as in most cases we need data from 1 or the other -- this sped things up a bit but it still seems like a big lag for a mere 40-80MB.

How do I speed things up, pref without affecting the entire PHP environment or files outside the folder this is hosted in.

Comment: Is it perhaps possible to turn it into a JSON data?

Comment: May I ask why you are using a serialized array instead of a database?

Comment: If there is not option to refactor to use a DB and you wrote: We utilise some of the array nodes as variables. Why not extracting the critical and important variables from the file to a new one, keeping it simple?

Comment: Scoots -- tldr: timelines & "creep"... What was once a few metrics derived from crunching a variety of data (so we'd do the intensive, slow crunching at night, and have the metrics ready to load fast for users by day) became many metrics, with filters and... I would LOVE to refactor to DB, but bloody time, budgets, priorities

Comment: @abestrad: array nodes, variables, object members -- are equivalent in terms of performance in this context.
BTW: (seperately) I was able to cut some extra time by writing the array to a php file and loading it directly rather than writing serialized and unserializing at run time...

Comment: can you share a snippet on how you are currently doing the unserialization at run time ? and is the serialized array just assigned to a variable at the top of the script?